# Stall speed requirement

Tags: stall

I calculated my stall speed at 22m/s.

For this stall speed, would it be a better idea to increase it to use in my calculations later on or leave it as it is?

I thought increase it a little to be on the safe side so that my other calculations are safer estimates?

Comment: Theory is never truth if you don't check your result in reality.

Comment: In theory, there is no difference between theory and practice. In practice, there is...

Comment: What exactly are you asking?  Are you asking about the minimum speed you should fly your airplane at or the minimum speed for some specific phase of flight (e.g. landing )? If this is not an academic exercise or simulator operation what type of aircraft are you speaking of?

Comment: You should use 23.459.

Answer (score 2):

You stick with your stall speed but add a safety factor to all speeds which are multiples of it. In most cases this has already been done for you, for example when takeoff requires 1.3$\times$stall speed to be reached to calculate take-off distance.